# Convertir String a date() en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

Estoy consumiendo de un arreglo (json) las fechas de inicio y de fin. éstas estan en formato de string. Quisiera saber como convierto esos string a un formato fecha yyy-mm-dd e imprimirlo en mi controlador con un alert.
pdta. Todo esto quiero hacer para luego obtener fechas que se encuentren en esas fechas dadas (inicio y de fin)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.fechas = [
  {"fechaInicio": "01-04-2016"},{"fechaFin": "05-08-2016"},
  ];

  for(i=0;i<$scope.fechas.length;i++){
    alert($scope.fechas[i].fechaInicio);//esto quiero convertir a formato fecha yyy-mm-dd
    alert($scope.fechas[i].fechaFin); //esto quiero convertir a formato fecha yyy-mm-dd
  }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el filtro [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) de angular o una librería de manipulación de fechas como [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Usando el filtro date puedes parsear tu fecha tanto en la vista como en el controller pero esto tiene como inconveniente que este filtro espera que tu fecha de entrada venga como tipo [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) o como una cadena en el formato [ISO 8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

Tus fechas vienen en un formato `dd-MM-yyyy`, el cual no es un estándard por lo que puedes usar manipulación de cadenas o expresiones regulares para lograr el efecto deseado siempre y cuando el formato de entrada no cambie. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    var fechaInicio, fechaFin;

    $scope.fechas = [{
      "fechaInicio": "01-04-2016"
    }, {
      "fechaFin": "05-08-2016"
    }];

    var parseDate = $filter('parseDate');

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.fechas.length; i++) {
      fechaInicio = parseDate($scope.fechas[i].fechaInicio);
      fechaFin = parseDate($scope.fechas[i].fechaFin);
      alert(fechaInicio);
      alert(fechaFin);

    }
  })
  .filter('parseDate', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var result = input;
      var format = /^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$/;
      var match = format.exec(input);
      if (input && match) {
        result = match[3] + '-' + match[2] + '-' + match[1];
      }
      return result;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="fecha in fechas">
    <li>Fecha inicio: {{fecha.fechaInicio | parseDate }}</li>
    <li>Fecha fin: {{fecha.fechaFin | parseDate }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Aquí te dejo otro usando moment.js que en mi opinión es más completo ya que puedes modificarlo fácilmente en el futuro a cualquier otro formato de entrada.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    var fechaInicio, fechaFin;

    $scope.fechas = [{
      "fechaInicio": "01-04-2016"
    }, {
      "fechaFin": "05-08-2016"
    }];

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.fechas.length; i++) {
      fechaInicio = moment($scope.fechas[i].fechaInicio, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      fechaFin = moment($scope.fechas[i].fechaFin, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      alert(fechaInicio);
      alert(fechaFin);

    }
  })
  .filter('parseDate', function() {
    // Lo mismo en un filtro
    return function(input) {
      var result = input;
      if (input) {
        result = moment(input, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      }
      return result;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="fecha in fechas">
    <li>Fecha inicio: {{fecha.fechaInicio | parseDate }}</li>
    <li>Fecha fin: {{fecha.fechaFin | parseDate }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar simplemente javascript

```
//Ej.    

$scope.date1 = new Date($scope.fechas[0].fechaInicio);
```

a partir de ahi ya tenes un objeto Date como variable, y podes usar los metodos disponibles de javascript

```
//Ej. 
alert($scope.date1.getFullYear()+"-"+($scope.date1.getMonth()+1)+"-"+$scope.date1.getDate());
```

[http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp][1]